# Plotting interactive arulesViz plots in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, interactive, arules

i need to display interactive association rules plot in shiny. For that i am using arulesViz package. But when i am trying to display interactive scatter plot  using the below:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$plot1<-renderPlot({
rules <- apriori(transaction_all[[as.numeric(input$level)]],parameter=list(support=input$support,confidence=input$confidence))
plot(rules, measure=c("support", "lift"), shading="confidence",interactive = TRUE)
})
```

Its throwing an error:

```
Error in convertUnit(x, unitTo, "x", "location", "x", "location", valueOnly = valueOnly) : 
 'x' argument must be a unit object
```

How could this be done?
Thanks

**ui.R looks like this**

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

#  Application title
headerPanel("Sliders"),

# Sidebar with sliders that demonstrate various available options
sidebarPanel(
# Simple integer interval
      selectInput("level", label = h3("select level to mine"), 
            choices = list("Level-1" = 1, "Level-2" = 2, "Level-3" = 3,"Level-4" = 4), 
            selected = 1),
sliderInput("support", "Support:", 
            min=0, max=1, value=0.5),
sliderInput("confidence", "Confidence:", 
            min=0, max=1, value=0.5),
width=3 
),

 mainPanel(
plotOutput("plot1")
 )
))
```

**Server.R looks like this**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$plot1<-renderPlot({
rules <- apriori(transaction_all[[as.numeric(input$level)]],parameter=list(support=input$support,confidence=input$confidence))
plot(rules, measure=c("support", "lift"), shading="confidence",interactive = TRUE)
})
})
```

Comment: Can you share a complete code example for debugging?

Comment: @MichaelHahsler: Hi, I have added the code

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a solution to this error yet, but from reviewing your code and my code I believe the error is generated because we are attempting to use an ***interactive*** arulesViz plot.